# Adding an image to WebParts DeclarativeCatalog

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, web-parts

I try to add an image banner as a catalog item, but it won't show the image at all. Do I have to wrap it in something or add a custom webpart for this functionality?

When I add the exact same code in an ordinary `WebPartZone` it shows the image correctly.

```
<asp:CatalogZone ID="CatalogZone1" runat="server">
    <ZoneTemplate>
        <asp:PageCatalogPart ID="PageCatalogPart1" runat="server" />
        <asp:DeclarativeCatalogPart ID="DeclarativeCatalogPart1" runat="server" >
            <WebPartsTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl="..." runat="server" />
            </WebPartsTemplate>
        </asp:DeclarativeCatalogPart>
    </ZoneTemplate>
</asp:CatalogZone>
```

Comment: I solved it by adding it to a custom user control. This was fine because I needed additional functionality anyway. I still would like to know why the original approach doesn't work though :)